# Unable to install libopenni2-dev

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Odroid XU3(Arm Processor), Ubuntu 12.04(Precise) and ROS(Hydro).
When I try to build my OpenNI2_camera, I got these error

-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
-- checking for module 'openni2'
--   package 'openni2' not found

Than I found out that installing libopenni2-dev will solve the problem, but when I try to apt-get install, I get these error

Package libopenni2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libopenni2-dev' has no installation candidate

I am new these programs, can anyone help me with this problem, Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201745/unable-to-install-libopenni2-dev/) by [Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/21449/xin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/21449/xin/) on 2015-01-26**:
I think I need a PPA to source for libopenni2-dev for Arm processor.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-08-15**:
Did you get this working? Im having the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about the history, but I found the binary repositories of `libopenni2-dev` has been migrated from ros.org to ubuntu.com.

On my Trusty

```
$ apt-cache policy libopenni2-dev
libopenni2-dev:
  Installed: 2.2.0.33+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.2.0.33+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0.33+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Xenial

```
$ apt-cache policy libopenni2-dev
libopenni2-dev:
  Installed: 2.2.0.33+dfsg-6
  Candidate: 2.2.0.33+dfsg-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0.33+dfsg-6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thus, OP was on Hydro then, make sure you specify `ros.org` as a source list, something [like this](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list) for your distro.

Also OP was on ARM. I doubt there was a binary build for openni2* packages for ARM on Hydro. In ROS Indigo [there is](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_arm.html?q=openni2) (and going onward I assume).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0